# How can I visualize the entire delete cascade of an existing database?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I have a PostgreSQL 9.6 database with 68 tables. Many of them have foreign key constraints with ON DELETE CASCADE clauses.

I would like to see the complete graph of the entire cascade. Is there a tool for that?

Comment: You mean specific to the row, or a possibility that the schema merely permits?

Comment: You can try the query at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578685/2521566 to use transitive closure to find the referencers and referencees of your FK's.

Comment: I recommend powerdesigner.This video will help you.[youtube.com/watch?v=1WU7Ar4Yph8](http://youtube.com/watch?v=1WU7Ar4Yph8)

Comment: Evan, the latter.

Answer (score 1):

[Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) has Diagram tool. Just drug and drop your tables and you'll see relationships

Comment: I am using Dbeaver to show the diagram. It's cool.

Comment: I drugged my tables and now they don't stand still and don't respect the foreign keys :D